# How to get realtime info on Uber button in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uber-api

I followed the official [documentation here](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/button/ios) and it claimed that by the end of the tutorial I would have a button that displays realtime info about the ride (ie. cost, distance from nearest driver in minutes).

I have read through all of the Uber documentation on deep links as well and I have found no references to acquiring real time data.

**Does anyone have any experience with displaying realtime data on their Uber button?**